# jQuery getJSON - reference pre-existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am using `jQuery.getJSON` to get some data. I have an object called `helpdesk.data.STATUS.MESSAGE.NOTLOGGEDIN` which is created in a normal script tag. In the JSON returned by the call to `getJSON`, I am trying to reference `helpdesk.data.STATUS.MESSAGE.NOTLOGGEDIN`. I am using the `.done` method to capture the JSON and do something with it, and `.error` to catch any errors.

The JSON being returned looks perfectly valid, however it is going into the `.error` function with a status of 200 (OK).

If I change the reference to the object to a string, it goes into the `.done` method. Does anyone know of a way to reference an object which already exists within the page firing the `getJSON` request from the JSON being returned?

The returned JSON is:

`{"builds": {"status": helpdesk.data.STATUS.FAILURE, "messages": [helpdesk.data.STATUS.MESSAGE.NOTLOGGEDIN]},"details": {"status": helpdesk.data.STATUS.FAILURE, "messages": [helpdesk.data.STATUS.MESSAGE.NOTLOGGEDIN]}}`

---

Final code:

```
$.ajax("/helpdesk/resources/js/json/data.json.php", {"data": {"data": "styling-builds,details", "update": "update", "nojson": "nojson"}}).done(function(data) {
    eval("data = " + data);
});
```

Comment: Note that your JSON is not valid (try to copy/paste it in http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: It has 4 errors on the objects I am referencing. What I'm trying to do is reference objects which already exist in the page before the call to getJSON.

Comment: Hmm perhaps using $.post (or $.ajax) with dataType set to json and then using JSON.parse or something similar would do it.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to reference variables in your JSON response

Comment: Ok, but the thing is this would be so much better if we can achieve this as all the possible errors are already stored in an object anyway. I'll try the $.post method and see if I get anywhere with that

Comment: IMHO the JSON response should be client-agnostic. That's why it doesn't really make sense to put variables in it.

Comment: I think you're right, for most cases. I think this case is an exception. I mean the site is built such that *every* page will definitely have these referenced objects, therefore we can guarantee they won't error. In cases where you have an absolutely huge site with lots of sections, where the header / footer / etc. may be different, that's where I agree that objects should not be referenced.

Comment: Or maybe an alternative solution is to return your JSON as a string response and call `eval` on it ?

Comment: Yeah, that is where I'm headed - wasn't sure whether it would be best to parse as JSON or `eval`, but I'm happy with either. Will do some research into which is best. Parsing as JSON may well face the same issues so I may be stuck with `eval`. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up: it is obviously incorrect to put references to client variables in your JSON response and it will result in invalid JSON format (cf http://json.parser.online.fr/).

The only workaround I see (if you really want to reference an existing variable in your JSON) is to return your response as a string and call `eval` on it on client-side (variables and functions will be correctly interpreted then).

Comment: Thanks. See updated post for final code. It is working perfectly now :). Along with global error handling (which will log an error in the DB via another ajax call) this is going to be very powerful!